# map is not a function React

Tags: reactjs

i am creating the simple system in Reactjs.when i enter the data in to the form and click the button data need to be append in to the table.but when i click the button i got the problem on

```
users.map is not a function
TypeError: users.map is not a function
```

some one solve my problems i am new comer of react.what i tried so far i attached below.please rectify the error

```js
import { useState } from "react";

function Test() {
  const [name, setName] = useState();
  const [salary, setSalary] = useState();
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  function Calculation() {
    setUsers([users, { name, salary }]);
  }

  return (
    <div class="container">
      <h3>Employee Salary Calculation</h3>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Employee Name</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          placeholder="Employee Name"
          onChange={(event) => {
            setName(event.target.value);
          }}
        />
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Salary</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          placeholder="Enter Salary"
          onChange={(event) => {
            setSalary(event.target.value);
          }}
        />
      </div>

      <button type="submit" onClick={Calculation} class="btn btn-primary mt-4">
        Submit
      </button>

      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {users.map((user) => (
            <tr>
              <td>{user.name}</td>
              <td>{user.salary}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Test;
```

Comment: Because, it not an array. You are setting state as object try to set as array of object

Comment: i did but table row not append. if i enter the new record of the form.prevois record in erased and add the new record please check the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting up another array inside the user state. Change the Calculation function as follow.

```
function Calculation()
{
  
  setUsers([...users,{ name, salary}]);
     

}
```

Comment: ...users  sir why we add ... before the users can you explain please

Comment: @JohnPeter it'll make a copy of the existing users array using spread operator. The way  your're using the Calculation function, it'll make a nested array inside the user state,  You can do some study on the spread operator.

Comment: One more thing, function  name should be started with lowercase while component name starts with uppercase letter.